# How to unit test NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, core-data, ocunit, ocmock

I am trying to write unit tests for a view controller that implements the [NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). The first test of the implementation (after some other tests of this view controller) is to verify that a table row is inserted into the table view when a new object is inserted.

My first implementation of the test was:

```
- (void) setUp {
    [super setUp];

    sut = [[JODataTableViewController alloc] init];
    fetchedResultsCtrlrMock = [OCMockObject niceMockForClass:[NSFetchedResultsController class]];
    NSError *__autoreleasing *err = (NSError *__autoreleasing *) [OCMArg anyPointer];
    [[[fetchedResultsCtrlrMock expect] andReturnValue:OCMOCK_VALUE((BOOL){YES})] performFetch:err];
    [sut setValue:fetchedResultsCtrlrMock forKey:@"fetchedResultsController"];
    [sut view]; // This invokes viewDidLoad.
}

- (void) tearDown {
    sut = nil;

    [super tearDown];
}

- (void) testObjectInsertedInResultsAddsARowToTheTable {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    id tableViewMock = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[UITableView class]];
    sut.tableView = tableViewMock;
    [[tableViewMock expect] insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]
                                  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];

    [sut controller:nil didChangeObject:nil
        atIndexPath:nil
      forChangeType:NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert
       newIndexPath:indexPath];

    [tableViewMock verify];
}
```

When it tried to implement the functionality in the view controller to move to the green status (TDD), I wrote the following code:

```
- (void) controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}


- (void) controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
    didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
      forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
       newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell;

    switch (type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath]
                                  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
            break;

    }
}


- (void) controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

However, I couldn't get it to pass and the error is:

```
Test Case '-[JODataTableViewControllerTests testObjectInsertedInResultsAddsARowToTheTable]' started.
Unknown.m:0: error: -[JODataTableViewControllerTests testObjectInsertedInResultsAddsARowToTheTable] : OCMockObject[UITableView]: unexpected method invoked: isKindOfClass:<??> 
Test Case '-[JODataTableViewControllerTests testObjectInsertedInResultsAddsARowToTheTable]' failed (0.001 seconds).
```

I tried to add one or more times the following line to the preparation part of the test with the same results.

```
[[[tableViewMock expect] andReturnValue:OCMOCK_VALUE((BOOL){YES})] isKindOfClass:[OCMArg any]];
```

As you can see, I am currently using `OCUnit` and `OCMock`. I would consider other tools only if it is impossible to create these kind of tests with this toolset, and in that case I would appreciate to an explanation of their limitations, should they exist.

As far as I understand, the mock is unable to "lie" about the nature of its class even when told to do so. Also, the error doesn't provide information about the class `UITableView` is looking for. I know that it isn't a good practice for testing to use `-isKindOfClass:`, but it isn't my code.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I haven't seen `expect` used together with `andReturn` like that before. I think you need to `stub` it…

Comment: @David I am using that successfully in other tests. Are you sure it is wrong?

Comment: No, I'm not sure. I haven't seen it before but doesn't mean it's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to work around mocking objects that have concealed inner behaviors is to use a partial mock. In your case:

```
id tableViewMock = [OCMock partialMockForObject:[[UITableView alloc] init]];
```

When I do this I usually change the name slightly and would call it `tableViewPartial`

Comment: You can also use tableViewMock = [OCMock partialMockForObject:sut.tableView];

Answer (score 0):

I've seen failures related to `isKindOfClass:` calls before, and they're usually the result of the way Apple implemented a certain feature in their own code. The standard `mockForClass:` will reject any unexpected messages as a failing situation. A simple solution is to switch your mock to `niceMockForClass:` which is forgiving about such unexpected messages.

Adding expectations for messages coming from third-party code would make your tests very coupled to external implementation details. Making sure `isKindOfClass:` gets called is clearly not an explicit requirement of your system.

Comment: Thank you for your idea. Funny enough, I use the nice mock, the test fails because, somehow, tableView becomes nil in the view controller (everything remains as in the question).

Comment: I also agree with your comment on the coupling. I am worried about this also. Is there any better way to implement the test?

Comment: What if you create a UITableView and partially mock it?

Comment: @BenFlynn This seems to work. I would be glad to accept your answer, if you write it as such. Thank you!